# Implementing a virtual file system tree using Neo4j

Tags: tree, neo4j, filesystems

I want to implement a virtual file system in neo4j. My question is **Is it the right way?**

And if it is is this sample cypher query good for getting contents of folder in file system?

```
MATCH (user:User {'id':1})-[:has]->
(:Directory {'name':'/'})-[:contains]->
(:Directory {'name':'test'})-[:contains]->
(:Directory {'name':'test2'})-[:contains]->
(:Directory {'name':'test3'})-[:contains]->(f:Directory|File)
Return f
```

Comment: what questions do you want to answer in your use case?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster I mean is it the right way to approach? And if it is, can neo4j handle deep nested trees?? Like accessing a directory with 1000 parent directories??

Comment: I've asked for what kind of queries you want to do in your graph. The query patterns influence the way you do graph modelling.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Just `match` query like the example and my concern is about query length in neo4j and the time it takes to find long paths.

Comment: Hamid the length of the chain isn't so problematic, yeah sure neo4j can do 1000 parent directories in this way.  Stefan is asking what you want to do with this data.  This is an OK way to model the data, but there might be a better way depending on what queries you'll ask.